# How to rapidly switch polarity of two plates?

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, polarity, reverse-polarity

If I have two metal plates, with P1 connected to V+, and P2 connected to GND, how can I alternate the polarity of these two plates? I wish to have P1 connected to GND, and P2 connected to V+. Then swap polarity again, and so forth. Is there such a circuit for this type of polarity switching?

Comment: What are the dimensions of the plates? And define 'rapidly'.

Comment: Are you building a synchrotron?

Comment: What is  V+ max?

Comment: It looks like I was overthinking this. I'm basically looking for an H-bridge sort of thing. A double-pole-double-throw switch as answered by Drew works too. I only need a switch of polarity once every second, or even longer intervals. The voltage would likely be 12V to feed the motor driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer will depend on how fast, and what voltage. For occasional switching you can use a dpdt relay wired as a reverser.

I found a tutorial for this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTGzcN8JrUk). If that dies just search "DPDT reverse switch" or "DPDT reverse relay".

To go faster (like many times per second), you'll want to use an H bridge. For lowish voltages, you can get a fully integrated module from amazon based on the [LM298N motor driver](https://smile.amazon.com/Controller-H-Bridge-Stepper-Mega2560-Duemilanove/dp/B01BWLICV4/).

For higher voltages, you might have to build your own H bridge using high voltage components.

Comment: Thank you. I apologize for the late response. I did some research and decided the H-bridge motor driver board is what I'm looking for. I can control the switching with an Arduino.